# JADE file is not loading socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I know that this might be a dumb question but im learning how to use WebSockets and im having troubles with this; 
This is where I Connect the socket server

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(global.server);
server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:8080');
  });
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('Un cliente se ha conectado');
   socket.emit('messages', messages);
   });
```

it works in the terminal I get the correct message, in the client view I have something alike;

```
extends ../layout
block content
script(src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js")
script(src='/javascripts/Enfermero/main.js')
```

And the js of that view....

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', { 'forceNew': true });

socket.on('messages', function(data) {
console.log(data);
 });
```

On the explorer I always get:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
at main.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Would you guys could help me? 
I have made some research but I kind of don't understand whats happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `script(src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js")` try using reference path `script(src="<path to socket.io>/socket.io/socket.io.js")`

Also, I think the `io` is initialised in the following way:

```
socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.connect();
```

Refer the documentation of client api here: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

simply use `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")`, socket.io.js is located in `node_modules/socket.io-client` so the path is known by the app.

Comment: ,copy soket.io.js from  /node_modules/socket.io-client/dist to you public folder , then refer to it from your page